# Modal Dialog Similar to jQuery UI

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF XAML file with the layout definition. It's based on a dock-panel.

I want to display an interestingly looking alert/info message, i.e. a frame on a semi-transparent background covering the original window contents. See this [jQuery UI example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation). I'd like to cover the back and display smt in the front (not necessarily a moving window - a static rectangle with text will be enough.

Is it possible to procedurally create such an effect in WPF?

Comment: What do you mean by procedurally?   You can create a Page and display it with the .ShowDialog method and it acts kind of like modal dialog box and you have the full XAML to format the page.

Comment: in HTML I can have a hidden div width 100% width and height that I can procedurally show and hide thus creating a nice info pop-up effect..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the "ChildWindow" control in the Extended WPF Toolkit:
http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ChildWindow

This acts just like the ChildWindow control in Silverlight. It allows a modal pop and adds a mask to the background.

Comment: It's a control. You ref it the same as a regular Window except this acts more like a modal popup.

Comment: Well, I didn't use the ChildWindow but the **BusyIndicator** instead. Works like a charm. You can read about it [here](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BusyIndicator). Thanks for the cluse.

Comment: I use it too. They took a few cues from Silverlight and put it in that toolkit. The BusyIndicator is one I use a lot.